# best method to append a 2D array

Tags: python, append

I have been pulling my hair on this one.
I want to create a an array with certain length. Then I will fill in these arrays with some 2D values of vectors.
What I excepted is

```
Array = [[[2,4]],[[3,4],[4,5]],[[5,7],[7,7],[8,9]]]
```

This is what I have: I tried both `numpy` append and array append both did not work. Appending the array with when I tried this `CCList[2].append([[3,4]])` it was append every second entry on the list. Then I tried this and when I execute this, I get an empty array why it does not append anything...

```
CCList = [[[]]]*3 # fixed length
# I tried the following, it did not work
#CCList[2].append([3,4])
np.append(CCList[3],[[1, 9]])
print(len(CCList))
print(CCList[2])
print(CCList[3])
print(CCList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you created your fixed-length array.  Do it like this:

```
CCList = [[] for _ in range(3)]

CCList[0].append([2,4])
CCList[1].append([3,4])
CCList[1].append([4,5])

print(CCList)
#[[[2, 4]], [[3, 4], [4, 5]], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another solution, as well:
you just have to make sure it is populated before doing `append`

```
if not CCList[1]:
    CCList[1] =  [[3,4]]
else: 
    CCList[1].append([2,3])
```